# Select the whole table using linq to Sql Except condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using linq to sql query to compare the result from two different tables. Say for example that my first table as got Id & Email columns and my 2nd table as got Email column alone. How do I use linq - Intersect/Except condition to select everything from the first table (including Id column) but not in the 2nd table.

I am using the linq query as shown below:

```
var result = table1.Select(t => t.Email).Except(table2);
```

The query works fine but the problem is, I can't get the Id values from the result unless I write another foreach loop.

eg:

```
foreach(var email in result) { table1.Where(t => t.Email.Equals(email)); }
```

Can someone suggest me how to get the whole table in my 1st query itself please?

Comment: Doesit have to be Intersect/Except? Can't you accept `.Where(!contains(...)` instead?

Comment: yes it can be & I tried using where condition which works fine but it takes awful lots of time when I do the comparison with about 500,000 result. eg: var val = table1.Select(t => t).Where(t => listOfEmailAsString.Except(s.Email));

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ToList()` at the end of the first query.  That forces the query to be executed, enumerated, and realized into the result instead of remaining as an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: .ToList() not going to help as I got to get Id value as well in my select query. var result = table1.Select(t => t.Email).Except(table2);